# ASP.NET MVC - How to Specify the Value in TextBox

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I specify the Value that should be entered into the Textbox. I dont want to use dropdownlist. I want to accept only these three (3) values **Nigeria, Ghana and Togo**

If any other value is entered it should not save or hide or disable the Save button.

**View**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.COUNTRY_NAME, "Country Name")                               
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.COUNTRY_NAME, new { @style = "border-radius:3px;", @type = "text", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Country Name", @autocomplete = "on" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.COUNTRY_NAME, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Please how do I achieve this?

Comment: you can use "jquery autocomplete" to achieve this......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit the form, you can validate textbox value by `jQuery`.

```
<button onclick="validateData();"></button>
```

Then write a validation method as follows.

```
function validateData() {
    if (Nigeria, Ghana and Togo) {
        //ajax post to your controller
    } else {
        //return error message
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two Options

1. You can use Server side [Custom Validator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668224.aspx) for Country_Name property.
2. Or Jquery validation on client side.

Comment: Please can you give a live scenario